# "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type" in dynamic index of type

Tags: typescript

I having trouble with setting typeof variable.

What I have :

```
let filterStatus:{
'`filter[or][${number}][status]`' ?:string
} = {};
```

and ${number} is dynamic and I want to assing to my var in this way :

```
filterStatus[`filter[or][${2}][status]`] = 'pending';
```

and typescript return this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"filter\[or\]\[2\]\[status\]"' can't be used to index type '{ '`filter[or][${number}][status]`'?: string | undefined; }'.
Property 'filter\[or\]\[2\]\[status\]' does not exist on type '{ '`filter[or][${number}][status]`'?: string | undefined; }'.
```

it's string structure that the backend wants me to send

see my example in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQGwpgLsBmCWITAJwMoQIYQK4GcBcA3gFDCnADkABnAsgNoD2SAunQCQEB2WAtgEbIAvqxwZsOZpXLAA-HlFJYnAOYlgg4AF5gBQQG4ih0uCjceW4ACYDamolRjcdavHuMW7ApeF1RmXJLMFuQADmCcACZKyuR6QA)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try ```record``` property of typescript ? here is the link [**record**](https://www.edureka.co/community/180621/what-is-record-in-typescript)

Comment: you could try this  :- [**your code**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAEoFwTwBwU1AMQJYBsJwE4GUIEMIBXAZ1AF5QAlOAYwHtMATAHmIk2QDsBzAGlDYceoAD6hCnRnABmXOIwB8AbhCo4EULPRZcBEgC4kaDDnxFSFAN4BfFSDCg1GzoQC25UACY7Wk7vMA2gAGvlgBDAC6AQAklp7WUWx6xBFBER4A5PCSXNwZKuAA9IWaxjpmJMGhmOGYUbHxiRUpaZnZjLn5QA)

Comment: thank you for your answer @DSDmark, Record is ok but it gets other properties as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property of `filterStatus` is currently not a *template literal type*. You just hardcoded it to be the string literal `filter[or][${number}][status]` which does not respect `${number}` to be placeholder for a number.

You will have to use a mapped type.

```
let filterStatus:{
  [K in `filter[or][${number}][status]`]?: string
} = {};
```

This will give the type of `filterStatus` an *index signature*. And those are allowed to be *template literal types*.

```
let num = 2;
filterStatus[`filter[or][${num}][status]`] = 'pending'; // valid
filterStatus[`filter[or][2][status]`] = 'pending';      // valid

filterStatus[`filter[or][abc][status]`] = 'pending'; // compile time error
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZglsYgE4GUwEMwFcDOAuA3gFAQQDaA0hDAHYQAGs8SpA9ogLqkAk+1mAtgCMkAX07Z0WbOzrsA-LggTENAOaEREALwR8IgNyFCoSH37aIAJkOMEKSTlIM4d1h268BY0hIw4Z7BYA5AAOINQAJmpB+hAA9HEQAG5owDARhLZIqH7YTlmIbpyW4g7SssFhkdGxJHUJyanpRgU5UvkuzGziLPwgqCrUqqW5AZXhUUMx8YkAxr0hcCAQYDB9EEiIbEA)

Comment: thanks it's exactly what I was looking for, could please tell me what K is doing?

Comment: `K` normally represents the type of the keys in a mapped type where `K` is substituted with each element of the union. But in this case, we don't have a union. So `K` is just the template literal type.